# Scifi movie or tv show, with psychic girl

Tags: story-identification

There was a part where the girl was with a bunch of other kids (orphans?) in a room with a skylight, and a white dove died somehow, and she covered it with her hands and brought it back to life. Also there was a scene where the girl and a man are trapped in a truck on railway tracks, and right before the train hit the girl made the truck vanish.

Comment: Forgot the name but it was a quickly cancelled series from a couple of years ago.  I will find it when I can get to a computer

Comment: Not [Orphan Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_Black), I take it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New thought. [Sole Survivor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sole_Survivor_(2000_film))  has a girl that can heal and teleport, so that might account for the healed bird and the disappearing truck. There are also more children involved, so it has that element as well. 
It was released in 2000, so the time frame is better as well.

Comment: I managed to track down a copy and this is it. The bird flies into a window while all the kids were outside, and right at the end (spoiler?) the girl teleports a campervan off the tracks just before the train hits. Thanks for figuring this out!

Answer (score 4):

[Believe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Believe_(TV_series)) had a scene with a girl resurrecting a dove and a skylight.

[Here's the IMDB link.](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2592094/) It has pictures and a trailer.

Comment: I don't think it was Believe, because I remember watching it in high school so it must have been around 1998-2000. But maybe I have mixed up two different shows with two different girls.